# Does $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(n-k)^k}{k!} $ have a closed-form expression in terms of $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Does $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(n-k)^k}{k!} $ have a closed-form expression in terms of $n \in \mathbb{N}$? It seems to grow a bit faster than $e^{0.5n}$, but there's clearly more to it, and I don't know how to look this up.

I know that:

$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k!} = e^z - 1$. I'm looking for a similar closed-form expression that eliminates the $k$.

$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!} = e^n \frac{\Gamma(n+1,n)}{\Gamma(n)} - 1$, where the $\Gamma$ ratio is close to 1/2.

$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-k)^k}{k!} $ diverges. (It makes no sense for my purpose anyway, once the $n-k$ goes negative and the exponents flip its sign.)

Thanks!

Comment: Is $z\in \mathbb N$? Since your series is finite, the question is not what it converges to but whether there is a closed form in terms of known functions.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I'm looking for a closed form in terms of z (with the k eliminated), analogous to the what's available with the simpler $z^k / k!$ sums.

Comment: So $z\in \mathbb R$. What do you mean for example by $\sum_{k=1}^\pi$? Note that the result involving the incomplete gamma function holds only for positive integer values of $z$. It would be better to use the symbol $n$ instead of $z$ since $z$ usually stands for a general complex number.

Comment: Sorry, $z \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Gary. I found $\Omega$ here. There must be something related to Lambert function. Any idea ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici If we start the sum at $k=0$ instead of $k=1$, the asymptotics $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^z {\frac{{(z - k)^k }}{{k!}}}  \sim \frac{1}{{1 + \Omega }}e^{\Omega z} 
$$ is extremely accurate. Here $\Omega =0.56714329040978\ldots$ satisfies $\Omega e^{\Omega}=1$. Note that if we replace $\Omega$ by $1$, we obtain the asymptotics for the sum expressed in terms of the incomplete gamma function. I have no idea at the moment how to prove this asymptotics.

Comment: @Gary. $\frac 1{1+\Omega}=0.6381037433651107785224074$. Bingo ! you got it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici There must be a proof based on discrete Laplace method.

Comment: Is is possible to exploit $$ e^{-r W_0(x)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{r(n+r)^{n-1}}{n!}(-x)^n $$ which holds for any $r\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|x|<1/e$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I added some thoughts about it to my answer.

Comment: @kevincrawfordknight Are you happy with any of the answers given below?

Comment: @Gary Exceedingly happy. The answer you showed is simple and easy to use, and your "First approach" proof let's me understand how this kind of thing works. I use Stirling's formula plenty, but I'm not as familiar with the other tools needed. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can obtain asymptotic approximations for large $n$ of this sum.

**First approach.** We approximate the sum by an integral and then approximate the gamma function by Stirling's formula. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(n - k)^k }}{{k!}}} &\sim \int_0^n {\frac{{(n - t)^t }}{{\Gamma (t + 1)}}\mathrm{d}t}  = n\int_0^1 {n^{ns} \frac{{(1 - s)^{ns} }}{{\Gamma (ns + 1)}}\mathrm{d}s} \\ & \sim \sqrt {\frac{n}{{2\pi }}} \int_0^1 {s^{ - 1/2} \exp \left( { - n\left( {s\log \left( {\frac{s}{{1 - s}}} \right) - s} \right)} \right)\mathrm{d}s} 
\end{align*}
as $n\to +\infty$. The integral may be evaluated asymptotically via the saddle point method:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 {s^{ - 1/2} \exp \left( { - n\left( {s\log \left( {\frac{s}{{1 - s}}} \right) - s} \right)} \right)\mathrm{d}s} & \sim (1 - s_0 )\sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{n}} \mathrm{e}^{ - n\left( {s_0 \log \left( {\frac{{s_0 }}{{1 - s_0 }}} \right) - s_0 } \right)} \\ & = \frac{1}{{1 + \Omega }}\sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{n}} \mathrm{e}^{\Omega n} 
\end{align*}
as $n\to +\infty$. Here $s_0  = \frac{\Omega }{{1 + \Omega }} = 0.361896 \ldots$ is the sole saddle point on the path of integration and $\Omega=0.5671432\ldots$ satisfies $\Omega \mathrm{e}^\Omega =1$. Therefore
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(n - k)^k }}{{k!}}}  \sim \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\Omega n} }{{1 + \Omega }}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. It seems that this approximation is extremely good. For example with $n=10$, the sum is $185.3375027557\ldots$, whereas the approximation yields $185.3375027898\ldots$. The alternative approach below shows the reason behind this accuracy.

**Second approach.** A different approach using generating functions yields a complete asymptotic expansion. We start with the [following power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Integer_and_complex_powers) involving the principal branch of the Lambert $W$-function:
$$
\exp (nW_0(z)) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{n(n - j)^{j - 1} }}{{j!}}z^j } ,
$$
valid for $|z|<\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$. Differentiating both sides gives
$$
\frac{{W_0(z)}}{{1 + W_0(z)}}\exp (nW_0(z)) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{j(n - j)^{j - 1} }}{{j!}}z^j } .
$$
Taking the difference of the two expansions, we find
$$
\frac{{\exp (nW_0(z))}}{{1 + W_0(z)}} = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(n - j)^j }}{{j!}}z^j } ,
$$
and hence
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(n - k)^k }}{{k!}}} & = [z^n ]\frac{{\exp (nW_0(z))}}{{(1 + W_0(z))(1 - z)}}
 = \frac{1}{{2\pi \mathrm{i}}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\frac{{\exp (nW_0 (z))\mathrm{d}z}}{{(1 + W_0 (z))(1 - z)z^{n + 1} }}} \\ & = \frac{1}{{2\pi \mathrm{i}}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\frac{{\mathrm{d}z}}{{W_0^n (z)(1 + W_0 (z))z(1 - z)}}}  = \frac{1}{{2\pi \mathrm{i}}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\frac{{\mathrm{d}t}}{{t^{n + 1} (1 - t\mathrm{e}^t )}}} .
\end{align*}
Accordingly,
$$
\frac{1}{{1 - z\mathrm{e}^z }} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(n - k)^k }}{{k!}}} } \right)z^n } ,
$$
provided $|z|<\Omega$. If $W_k$ denotes the $k$th branch of the Lambert $W$-function, then
$$
\frac{1}{{1 - z\mathrm{e}^z }} - \sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^{ \infty } {\frac{1}{{1 + W_k (1)}}\frac{1}{{1 - z\mathrm{e}^{W_k (1)} }}} 
$$
is an entire function of $z$ (note that $W_{ \pm k} (1) =  - \log (2\pi k) \pm (2k - \frac{1}{2})\pi \mathrm{i} + o(1)$ for $k\ge 1$). Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(n - k)^k }}{{k!}}}  \sim \sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^{ \infty } {\frac{{\mathrm{e}^{W_k (1)n} }}{{1 + W_k (1)}}}  = \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{\Omega n} }}{{1 + \Omega }} + 2 \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{  \infty } \operatorname{Re}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{W_k (1)n} }{1 + W_k (1)} ,
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. In particular,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(n - k)^k }}{{k!}}} = \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{\Omega n} }}{{1 + \Omega }} + \mathcal{O}(\mathrm{e}^{n\operatorname{Re} W_1 (1)} ) = \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{\Omega n} }}{{1 + \Omega }} + \mathcal{O}(\mathrm{e}^{ - 1.5339133 \ldots \times n} ),
$$
showing why the leading order asymptotics is so accurate.

Comment: (+1) Great work!

Comment: This is superb ! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(n-k)^k}{k!}$$ made me thinking about Lambert function.

A quick and dirty linear regression with high accuracy
$$\log(S_n)=a+b\,n$$ shows  $b=W(1)=\Omega$.

Looking at $\big[\log(S_n)-\Omega\,n\Big]$ shows an asymptotic value equal to $a=-0.44925440\cdots$ which is not identified by inverse symbolic calculators.

However $e^a=0.638103743365111$
is extremely close to the largest root of the quadratic $9280 x^2 - 6351 x + 274=0$
$$\frac{6351+\sqrt{30164321}}{18560}=0.638103743365052$$

Computing a few numbers for
$$T_n=\frac{6351+\sqrt{30164321}}{18560}\,e^{\Omega\,n}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & T_n & S_n \\
 10 & 1.85338\times 10^{02}    & 1.84338 \times 10^{02} \\
 20 & 5.38314\times 10^{04}    & 5.38304  \times 10^{04}\\
 30 & 1.56353\times 10^{07}    & 1.56353\times 10^{07} \\
 40 & 4.54129\times 10^{09}    & 4.54129\times 10^{09} \\
 50 & 1.31902\times 10^{12}    & 1.31902\times 10^{12} \\
 60 & 3.83110\times 10^{14}    & 3.83110\times 10^{14} \\
 70 & 1.11274\times 10^{17}    & 1.11274\times 10^{17} \\
 80 & 3.23197\times 10^{19}    & 3.23197\times 10^{19} \\
 90 & 9.38727\times 10^{21}    & 9.38727\times 10^{21} \\
 100 & 2.72654\times 10^{24}   & 2.72654\times 10^{24} \\
 200 & 1.16502\times 10^{49}   & 1.16502\times 10^{49} \\
 300 & 4.97796\times 10^{73}   & 4.97796\times 10^{73} \\
 400 & 2.12702\times 10^{98}   & 2.12702\times 10^{98} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Note that $e^{ - rW_0 (x)}  = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{r(k + r)^{k - 1} }}{{k!}}( - x)^k }$ for any $r \in \mathbb C$ and $|x|<1/e$. Thus formally, $e^{nW_0 (1)}  = n\sum_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(n - k)^{k - 1} }}{{k!}}}$ which somewhat resembles $S_n$.

Comment: @Gary. This is exactly why I immediately thought about Lambert

Answer (score 2):

By Lagrange's inversion theorem
$$ e^{-r W_0(x)} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{r(n+r)^{n-1}}{n!}(-x)^n $$
holds for any $r\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|x|<\frac{1}{e}$. By replacing $x$ with $z e^z$ we get
$$ e^{-r z} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{r (k+r)^{k-1}}{k!}(-ze^z)^k $$
and by picking $r$ as $-n$
$$ \exp(n z) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{n(n-k)^{k-1}}{k!}(z e^z)^k $$
allowing to deduce Gary's bound from the dominated convergence theorem (the tail $\sum_{k>n}$ decays pretty fast, also due to the alternating signs).